# converted eclipse (JUnit) project into mvn and run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, m2eclipse

I have a an eclipse project, which mainly consist of JUint test cases, it has a dependency on other libraries.
My issue:- now I need to upload this project on Github and others don't need to install eclipse in order to run it. 
So I have to convert it to Maven and write a simple script for running this project,

1. After converting, it is possible to run it without eclipse and m2e plugin?
2. I have convert it to maven, but I don't understand how t run it without eclipse, I have a successfully build, however I can't run it.
3. Please could  you provide me a simple guide to how convert > build > run maven project after converting which mainly have a JUint tests.

   - because I didn't get the way to run JUint test with converted maven project
   - what should I use for the goal in the run configuration

Comment: Add the test cases to `src/test/java`, then build with `mvn test` - this will compile whatever is in `src/main/java`, then compile and run tests found in `src/test/java`.

Comment: how to do it using command line

Comment: there is no run option for maven at eclipse, only build

Comment: I'm talking about commandline - do you have Maven installed? To run from commandline, you need to install (dedicated) Maven, add its `bin` folder to system `PATH`, then you'll be able to run it using `mvn` commandline command.

Comment: I installed it, but what are the parameters for the mvn?

Comment: The simplest form is `mvn <goals>`, when run from the root of the artifact (i.e. from the directory the `pom.xml` is in). The goals are intelligent in that a specified goal implies all previous steps needed to run it, so you only need to specify `mvn test` to compile and run the tests.

Comment: I use mvn exec:java, I have this error::
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (d
efault-cli) on project try: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.moj
o:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: I run < mvn test >
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
3:compile (default-compile) on project try: Compilation failure: Compilation fai
lure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/htheiabat/workspace/try/src/test/java/trytest.java:[3,24] pack
age org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/htheiabat/workspace/try/src/test/java/trytest.java:[8,17] pack
age org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/htheiabat/workspace/try/src/test/java/trytest.java:[12,10] can
not find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class test.java.trytest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: @JiriTousek I have a successfully build, but I can't see the run? how to run it?